# accounting data model for government

Tags: database-design

looking for conceptual data model for very small government organization accounting system

can someone please draw out a very simple conceptual data model for a double-entry government accounting system?

thanks,

Alex Glaros

Comment: sqlvogel answered my question but I cannot find a check mark on the page to mark it as answered

Comment: Alex, I have now added an answer instead of a comment. You should be able to mark the question as answered if you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Government organizations use the same accounting systems that everyone else does, so it probably makes sense to look at the documentation provided by accounting software vendors. Conceptually, accounting systems are all much the same.

Bill Inmon and Len Silverston have published several books of industry data models that might be worth checking out. Personally, I haven't read them.